# Integrate help in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, integration

I have been using Sandcastle Help File Builder to produce help files (HTML 1.0) and it's working pretty descent. However, Sandcastle Help File Builder gives you the opportunity to generate HTML 2.0 output, which is what is used in Visual Studio help system.

But what I haven't figured out is how can I integrate the HTML 2.0 help produced by SandCastle in Visual Studio.

Does anyone has a procedure (the steps needed) to make this happen?

**Note:**
Though I'm interested in any suggestions and tools you may have in mind, I would prefer the answers to focus on using Sandcastle (and Sandcastle Help File Builder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the note is not relevant.

Ok, you have HTML 2.0 help? Now you need to INTEGRATE it. There is nothing in sandcaastle to do that...
...look up HxMerge on the internet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164570%28VS.80%29.aspx

This is the tool needed to integrate your .hxs files into the visual studio help.

Btw., the "Sandcastle Help File Builder" is NOT a "Sandcastle Help File Builder", it is the "Help File Builder" - which existed long before Sandcastle. It is part of the HTML Help toolkit from Microsoft.

Comment: I think the note is pretty relevant. I am also specific: I'm more interested in "SandCastle Help File Builder" (http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB). But any other suggestion is also welcomed.